# Can I replace a laptop keyboard in a Lenovo L560 with a keyboard from a Lenovo E560?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo L560 laptop and — unfortunately — some keys are aren’t working, so I need to replace it.

In my region there is only Lenovo E560 laptop available for purchase. It looks like the two models are same at size and pin count.

Is it possible to use that keyboard on my current laptop? Is there any restriction for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say categorically that both the L560 and E560 keyboards are compatible or not,
but my searches on Amazon found keyboard replacements that are advertised as
compatible with one but not with the other.

You can try both searches:

- [Lenovo E560 keyboards](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Lenovo+E560+keyboard&ref=nb_sb_noss_2)
- [Lenovo L560 keyboards](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Lenovo+L560+keyboard&ref=nb_sb_noss_2)

Searches for one keyboard replacement for both keyboards at once came up as empty.

My conclusion is that both models are not compatible on keyboards.